# Finding application dependency for a program written in Mono

Tags: ubuntu, installation, mono, ubuntu-10.04

I developed a fairly mid-sized Mono tool on my Ubuntu 10.10 machine (Meverick) compiled with Mono 2.6. The program runs fine without any problem. Then I gave the tool to one of my colleagues for testing who is still using Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid) and Mono 2.4. He is not able to run the program. We upgraded Mono on his machine to 2.6 using badgerports' script but no luck. It runs but crashes immediately with SEGSIGV error. I doubt it is because we are missing a lib package on his machine. But how should I go and find out what dependencies he needs to run the program? I'm aware that there is a section where you can put what libs you need while creating a .deb installer. But what libs and what versions should I include for checking?

Comment: Please post the whole output.

Comment: Please run it in gdb and post the backtrace when the sigsegv happens.

Comment: Have you found a solution in the mean time? I've just run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe getlibs is your answer:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=474790

or a simpler way is here:
add http here because I can't post second link 
linux.byexamples.com/archives/409/how-to-list-shared-library-dependencies-used-by-an-application/

basically use ldd -v on your program to see what's required.

The first solution installs the stuff required for you.
The second gives you a list of what's required.

w

Comment: ldd is not working. This is what I'm getting: not a dynamic executable.

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of Mono [AsmSpy](https://github.com/mikehadlow/AsmSpy) does the trick.
Worked just fine with current stable (Mono 4.4.2) - I downloaded the [prebuilt version from AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/rahulpnath/asmspy/history).